# Transmission via RF433Hz Transmitter/Receiver pair failing AVR

Tags: microcontroller, avr, wireless, 433mhz

I am trying to send data wirelessly through a RF433Hz receiver/transmitter pair, but nothing seems to want to work.I want to the transmitter to continuously send a number (0x81) to the receiver when I press an active low button, I am expecting to see Ox81 on the receiver side but I am not seeing that.

```
int main( void )
{
        //initializeUART ( BAUD , DoubleAsync, DataBitLength, Parity, Stopbits )
        iniUSART0( 1200 , 0 , 8 , 0 , 2 );

        //Code for transmitter
        if(Transmitter)
        {        
            DDRA = 0xff;
            while(1){                        
                        if( bit_is_clear(PINB, 0) )
                        {          
                             data = 0x81;   
                             TransmitData(data);
                             PORTA = 0x81;
                        }
                     }
         }


      //Code For receiver
      if(Receiver)
      { 
      DDRA = 0xff;      
        while(1)
        {    
                     while(!flag)
                     {
                        data = ReceiveData();                           
                        PORTA = data;
                     }
        }        

}
```

The methods have been put in a separate header file and can be seen below

```
 unsigned char ReceiveData(void)
    {
        while ( ! UCSR0A & ( 1 << RXC0)) //Check if there ids data waiting for you
        {

        }
        return UDR0; //return data
    }

    void TransmitData( unsigned char data)
    {
        while( !UCSR0A & ( 1 << UDRE0)) //Check if uC is ready to transmit
        {

        }
        UDR0 = data; //Transmit Data
    }


    void iniUSART0(int baud, char doubleAsync, char dataLength, char parity, char numberOfStopBits)
    {

        int UBRR_Value = lrint ( (F_CPU / (16L * baud)) - 1 );

        UBRR0H = (unsigned char) (UBRR_Value >> 8);  //Upper Baud number
        UBRR0L = (unsigned char) UBRR_Value; //Put remainder in lower bits

        //Enable reception and transmission
        UCSR0B |= (unsigned char) (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);


        if(numberOfStopBits == 2)
        {
            UCSR0C |= (1 << USBS0);
        }   
        else 
        {
            UCSR0C &= ~(1 << USBS0);
        }       

        //Use an 8-Bit length data bit
        UCSR0C |= (unsigned char) (1 << UCSZ00);



        //Double Asynchronous mode?
        if(doubleAsync) UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0); 

        //Set the data bit length

          if ( dataLength == 6) UCSR0C |= ( 1 << UCSZ00 );
          if ( dataLength == 7) UCSR0C |= (1 << UCSZ10);
          if ( dataLength == 8) UCSR0C |= (1 << UCSZ10) | (1 << UCSZ00);

         if(parity == 2)UCSR0C |= (1 << UPM10); //Sets parity to EVEN
         if(parity == 1)UCSR0C |= (1 << UPM10) | (1 << UPM00); //Sets parity

 to ODD
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you try your code through wires and see what happens. If it works you'd know that it's something wrong with the radio modules.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to start with the lower possible baud-rate, perhaps 150bps. If you achieve success, then move up to progressively higher rates.

Comment: I will try that, so the lower the BAUD rate the higher the accuracy? I tend to see a lot of example code have 1200 or 2600 and thats the only reason I chose it.

Comment: Well, in theory, with the UART used for encode/decode, 2400bps should be doable, but characteristics of RF communication might come into play, including any interference. For 433MHz band, there are quite a few sources of potential interference s.a. garage-door controllers, wireless thermostats, wireless intrusion-detection-systems (older/cheaper kinds), and not just from your own home/office, but the neighborhood as well. I've managed to eek out about 120bps using software bitbanged mode, of using ASK/OOK 433MHz modules.

Comment: I've lowered the baud rate to 50 but I still can't get the 433's to work nicely, they seem to only receive noise unless I physically connect the antennas(2 long pieces of bare wire) together.Is there any other thing I could do to improve reception? Will buying proper antennas help improve reception drastically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally using a UART and simple communications scheme with low-cost RF modules isn't a good idea. A few problems you'll encounter:

- The receivers like a DC balanced signal (equal number of ones and zeroes) otherwise the data slicer won't operate correctly. Your example of `0x81` is `10000001` in binary that contains a long string of zeroes.
- Data received over RF can have quite a bit of skew by the time the end of the byte has been received. Most hardware UARTs designed for wired communications don't cope with that well.
- Before sending data you'll normally need a preamble to give the receiver time to lock.
- The receivers will receive random data when no carrier being modulated correctly is present, so you'll want a way to detect a valid packet / data.

RF Monolithics have a good application note [Unique Considerations for Data Radio UARTs](http://www.rfm.com/products/apnotes/an43.pdf) that explores and explains these issues. Some time ago I implemented the basic PLL receiver technique they describe along with some higher level error detection and  packet control that worked well.

That was quite a bit of effort but now the [VirtualWire](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_VirtualWire.html) project is available that performs all those functions. It's targeted at an Arduino but should be fairly straightforward to move across to other AVR based platforms (or other architectures for that matter).